# Disable search Input field hide/show functionality of Magento 2

Tags: search, magento2.2.6

I have to remove default search input hide/show functionality of magento 2.

currently in responsive view when we click on search Icon search input field is displaying. when we click on label of focus in input it's adding "active" class to form and lable.

I have to remove this and add custom jquery code to hide/show search input.

Comment: so you want to totally remove top search block? have you tried to remove it in layout.xml of you custom theme?

Comment: No I don't want to remove search block. Just want to remove hide/show input field functionality

Comment: any solution , i need same here.